# Builds not working on new server after move - TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Having moved our instance of TFS and it's databases over to our new server, everything seems to be working OK except for the builds. I can't get any of them working.
The build service is running as `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`, which is a member of the Project Collection Build Service Accounts group.

I think it could be because inside our LAN, we cannot browse to tfs using our external ip address (shown in the message below as x.x.128.153:8001/tfs).  Is there a way to fix this?  Where can I change the url that it is trying to use?

See details below:

- TFS 2013 r5
- Windows Server 2012 r2

Error message:

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \SCC\Test Build: 
Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (type AggregateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.ProcessTemplate.Download(String sourceGetVersion)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: An error occurred while sending the request. (type HttpRequestException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.HttpClientExtensions.<DownloadFileFromTfsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Unable to connect to the remote server (type WebException)Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond x.x.128.153:8001 (type SocketException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

Comment: TFS has a Server Uri and a Notification Uri. I suspect that you need to update these to return the accessible name.

Comment: If you mean the Uris in the App Tier Summary of the TFS Admin Console, those already have the local machine names in them.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yes, those are the ones I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working.  Looks like all I needed to do was to disable loopback checking in the router to get the ip based url to work.